# Is it alright for a English YA novel to have anime illustration?

Tags: novel, young-adult, artwork, light-novel

In the beginning, I want write and self publish (or traditionally publish if possible) a original English light novel (OELN). But The more write and the more I study on how to be a professional writer with proper prose, I begin to favor more with narrative driven story telling in standard YA instead of dialogue driven in light novel. But I love the idea of 4-8 page of anime illustration in light novel.

Plus, English YA novel seems to have (from what I've gathered) has a larger audience base compared to English translated light novel or OELN, since light novel has a very niche audience outside of Japan.

Here's the question. Is it a good idea to have YA with anime illustration? Will it turn out weird and turn off huge number of people. I really like more thought and opinion on this. Thank You

Comment: My answer here should help you decide, and explain why cleaner "anime-illustration" is used rather than more realistic style: [Do I need less exposition if I'm going to add images?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/40147/23253)

Comment: Your explanation did help reinforce my reason to have anime illustration, but the purpose of the question is more of aesthetic reasons. Whether majority of the YA reader would be okay, hate or love it?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I see a book cover that's anime looking I'll think that's it's a manga/graphic novel or a light novel. But if you want to cater to the general young adult audience I think you should try using a more traditional approach for you book cover.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know about Japan, but here in the U.S. I think an anime style cover would immediately shut off a lot of readers who will assume it's an anime comic, or a book based on an existing anime series. Even for readers interested in those books, the first group may be disappointed to open the book and find out it isn't a comic, and the second group may not be interested as they would likely be looking for series they are already familiar with.